# Network drive after restart disconnect

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, network-drive

I need advice.
I run a script on my computer that copies the files to the network drive. Periodically, it turns on via the task scheduler.
But it happens that after a reboot the network drive does not connect - even though when I set it up I checked "reconnect at login". (Usually I just double-click on the drive and it reconnects). But if I don't do this, the script can't put it anywhere because the disk doesn't seem to be there.

[image]

I tried:

- turning off fast booting,
- put a batch file in the folder after boot:

  ```
  @echo Create new Y: drive mapping
    net use Y: \\server\folder
    :exit
  ```
- put another batch file in the "after boot" folder

  ```
    @echo off

    :Start
    timeout /t 5 /nobreak >NUL
    if exist Y:\NUL goto End
    net use Y: \\server\folder /USER:domain\user password /PERSISTENT:YES
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Start
    :End
  ```

But neither solved the problem.

Comment: There is a space character missing between `password` and `/PERSISTENT:YES`. However, please note that a network drive connection is a per user account configuration and not a local machine configuration. The persistent storage of which network resources should be connected to which drive letter are stored in Windows registry hive `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. The automatic network drive reconnection is done only on user logged in.

Comment: What is not good documented is the fact that once using `/PERSISTENT:NO` for any network connection like in a batch file with `net use`, __all__ network connections stored in registry are disabled for automatic reconnection. That is of course unexpected by everyone. Every user expects `/PERSISTENT:NO` to be used only for the network drive connection currently made with `net use` in the batch file, but Windows toggles the global setting for all network drive connections for the current user account.

Comment: @Mofi I have incorrectly adjusted the code gap there normally is. Yes, it is only one and only the same user. But it still didn't work for me. The unit always turned out to be unconnected.

Comment: Note that Windows 10 does not wait for started network service before a user can sign in and desktop is shown and the shortcuts in AutoRun folder in Windows start menu are executed by Windows shell. So it is possible that the network is not available at all on autorun batch file being executed. Well, the second batch file should check that, but better would be something like using `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe -n 1 %server% >nul || ( %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 >nul & goto Retry )` with `:Retry` above this line.

Comment: Then make the network connection with `%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use Y: \\server\folder /USER:domain\user password /persistent:yes` (or `/persistent:no`) and do a file system access on any file or folder like `if exist Y:\* echo \\server\folder connected as drive Y:`.

Comment: @Mofi Can you post this solution to answer in complete form? I think I partially understand, but I don't know how you think it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem some days ago.
The solution I used was nothing really professional, but it worked.

I just created a textfile via powershell within the networkfolder.
Everytime I now restart my PC it just writes the newest date in this txt.
I know its not perfect, but it works.

```
New-Item \\Server\Folder\RecentLogin.txt
$var_date = Get-Date
Set-Content \\Server\Folder\RecentLogin.txt "$var_date"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you write that to the file manually (manually run script) or what? Maybe I'm just misunderstanding.

Comment: No, actually I just threw the .ps1 file into my autostart folder.
Press Win+R and then input "shell:startup" and run it. Just put the file in there and it should run at every startup.

Comment: Okey, Thank you for explanation. I try it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that [fast boot is disabled](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10).
2. Go to the Device Manager -> Network adapters -> Properties of your network adapter

- Under "Power Management" disable "Allow the Computer to Turn Off This Device to Save Power"
- Under "Advanced" set "Wait for Link" to "On"

3. Go to Group Policies (execute gpedit.msc) -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon and enable "Always Wait for the Network at Computer Startup and Logon".
4. Add the following values to your registry:

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
   "EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001
   "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000001

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
   "GpNetworkStartTimeoutPolicyValue"=dword:0000003c

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider]
   "RestoreConnection"=dword:00000001

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache]
   "Start"=dword:00000002

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
   "Autodisconnect"=dword:ffffffff

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
   "LocalKnownFoldersMigrated"=dword:00000001
5. Remove the following registry entries, if they exist (where "X" is the letter of your connected network drive):

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\X]

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Map Network Drive MRU]
   "a"="\Server\Path"
   "MRUList"="a"
6. Reboot
7. Map your network drive manually:

- open the File Explorer, right click on "This PC" and select "Map network drive"
- use the IP instead of the DNS name (e.g. `\\192.168.0.10\MyShare`) and activate "Reconnect at sign-in"

8. Add the following value to the corresponding registry key (where "X" is the letter of your connected network drive)

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\X]
   "ProviderFlags"=dword:00000001
9. Optionally: Delay any existing tasks which access the network drive to about 10 seconds.
10. Reboot and check if everything works as expected. The status of `net use` (shell command) should say "OK".